# Command takes effect before environment

Tags: macros, longtable

Is it possible to add a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` inside, .e.g., longtable (or other environment} to take effect before the environment starts? MWE which has no effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\vspace{-\baselineskip} \\ % this has no effect
                           % why \\ are really needed since caption has them?
\caption{testing table} \\
\hline
aaaa & bbbb \\
cccc & dddd \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

There is a MWE with the problem of having a messed reference in the LOT.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
%\usepackage{threeparttable} % the package below already loads it
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\chardef\TPT@@@asteriskcatcode=\catcode`*
\catcode`*=11
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\threeparttable\endcsname
    {\TPT@hookin{tabular}}
    {\TPT@hookin{tabular}\TPT@hookin{tabu}} % allow threeparttable with tabu
    {}{}
\catcode`*=\TPT@@@asteriskcatcode
\makeatother

\makeatletter % fix referencing of LOT while using longtabu
    \newcounter{dummy}
    \newcommand{\setdummy}{\refstepcounter{dummy} \\}
    \let\oldlongtabu\longtabu\def\dummytabu{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\oldlongtabu} % correct the \\ in \setdummy
    \def\enddummytabu{\endlongtabu}
    \def\dummycap{\setdummy\caption}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\listoftables

\bigskip

\blindtext

% LOT reference does not work
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] \label{tn:aa} A note
\item[b] Another note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtabu}{ll}
\caption{A long table 1}
\label{tab:test1} \\
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endhead
\cmidrule{2-2}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{continued}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
% the contents of the table
A& B\tnotex{tn:aa} \\
\midrule
%\newpage % just testing page break
C\tnote{b} & D \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\blindtext

% LOT reference works fine
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] \label{tn:bb} A note
\item[b] Another note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{A long table 2}
\label{tab:test2} \\
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endhead
\cmidrule{2-2}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{continued}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
% the contents of the table
A& B\tnotex{tn:bb} \\
\midrule
%\newpage % just testing page break
C\tnote{b} & D \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\blindtext

% LOT reference works fine (with vskip correction)
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] \label{tn:cc} A note
\item[b] Another note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{dummytabu}{ll}
\dummycap{A long table 3}
\label{tab:test3} \\
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
\endhead
\cmidrule{2-2}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{continued}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
% the contents of the table
A& B\tnotex{tn:cc} \\
\midrule
%\newpage % just testing page break
C\tnote{b} & D \\
\end{dummytabu}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\baselineskip` is zero in a tabular. Use some other length, then e.g. `\vspace{-1cm}` or `\\[-1cm]` will work. Or move the `\vspace` before the longtable.

Comment: But when I use \\ inside tabular, what is the actual skip of \\? I thought it was `\baselineskip`. For example, if used a `\macro{}\\` just after longtable what is the actual value of \\?

Comment: The defaut size of a row is height + depth of `\@arstrutbox`.

Comment: How can I store that value in a variable? like `let\tmpvar\@arstrutbox`

Comment: That's not a value but a box. You can find its definition/content in latex.ltx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] \label{tn:aa} A note
\item[b] Another note
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtabu}{ll}
\noalign{\phantomsection}
\caption{A long table 1}
\label{tab:test1} \\
\toprule
...
```

The links seem to work and no additional space is added.

Comment: @cacamailg I tried to patch some command in order to get this automatically, but `scrartcl`, `longtable`, `caption` and `ltcaption` juggle with `\caption` and its internal versions and the moment of the final redefinition is hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

`longtable` inserts a vskip of the length `\LTpre` (defaulting to `\bigskipammount`) before the table so to change the vertical space before the table alter this length with `\setlength` or `\addtolength`. Using `\vspace` in the position you show puts it in the first cell of the first row which is a `l` entry so a horizontal box in which a vertical skip does nothing. So the effect is just to *add* a blank line before the table despite nominally specifying a negative skip.

Comment: The problem is that I want to add a macro just after the `begin{longtable}` like `\macro{}`. I need that to correct the referring system. Since I need to put `\macro{} \\` I need before the longtable to remove the extra vertical space. So what I wanted is to include that correction inside the macro. I did it like that:

\makeatletter
\newcounter{dummy}
\AtBeginDocument{
     \newdimen\dummyskip
 \dummyskip\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setdummy}{
 \vspace{-\dummyskip}
 \refstepcounter{dummy}\addtocounter{dummy}{-1} \\}
\makeatother

I'm just not if there is side effect.

Comment: just after \begin{longtable} isn't a place to add code that is where lontable is parsing its optional and mandatory arguments. The only sensible place to add code would be before longtable `\let\oldlongtable\longtable\def\longtable{\mymacro\oldlongtable}` would make `\mymacro`  be executed before each table. I'm not sure what effect you intend with the `\refstepcounter{dummy}` setting a ref at begin document can have some side effects on vertical space in some circumstances, but I'm not sure why you are making a ref to that point. The \vspace{-\dummyskip} will have no effect at that point.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I am trying to use threeparttablex (which is based on threeparttable) and longtabu (because I want tablewidth with textwidh). longtabu uses longtable. with longtable the reference in LOT is ok (threeparttablex + longtable), but with lontabu it points to section that does not exist. With `\refstepcounter{dummy}` it point to the correct table, but I do not understant why. If I could I would avoid to use it.

Comment: so you have a label badly positioned with respect to the caption. You certainly don't want to add any dummy counters or spacing commands to fix that. As always it is 1000 times easier to help if you edit the question to contain a _complete_ _small_ document that shows the problem.

Comment: Edited to add a MWE with the error. The first table does not present a correct link in LOT, while the remaining two do. The last one has the "fix" with `\refstepcounter{}`.

Comment: @cacamailg Maybe `\phantomsection` is better than `\refstepcounter{dummy}`.

Comment: @egreg, perhaps, but the real question is why the label isn't picking up the table as the reference context. I can not see why longtable/longtabu would be used in threeparttable. That is a boxed float so no page breaking can happen so longtable provides nothing and it has its own caption and notes mechanism so the longtable caption and note mechanism is similarly redundant.

Comment: Well, the threeparttablex allows the use of a construction similar to threepartable but does allow page break. I am using that because, as far as I know, longtable/longtabu will place footnotes at the end of the page. But I would like them just after the table end. That is why I am trying to use it instead of the regular `\footnote{}/\footenotetext[]{}/\footnotemark[]`. @egreg I will try `\phantomsection`.

Comment: @egreg, probably the best approach is to include `\phantomsection` inside the `\makecaption{}` macro when using longtabu. But I didn't find it inside tabu.sty, so I assume it uses the longtable code for that.

\makeatletter
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\phantomsection\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

Probably the place of `\phantomsection` here is not the best